# Person I Like vs Person Who Likes Me

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, colloquial-language

From what I understand 好きな人 refers to "the person I like".
How do I express "the person who likes me"?

Preferably the most naturally casual way.

I want to use it in casual sentences like the following:

> 今、好きな人がいないよ。笑

Answer (score 5):

好きな人 isn't necessarily about you. It is assumed to be since no specifics were given.

There are many ways you could express it but here are a few examples.

> 好きな人がいない
>   There is no one I like.
>
> 好きな人がいますか？
>   Is there a person you like?
>
> 私の事が好きな人がいるでしょうか
>   I wonder if there is someone who likes me.